# Get everything before a certain character in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I got the following entries in my database:

```
E01234-1-1
E01234444-1-800000000
```

I want to trim the entry so I get:

```
E01234-1
E01234444-1
```

So basically, I want everything before the second '-' regardless of the length

How can I solve it?  Im using MS SQL SERVER 2012

I am using this but it only bring data from before first hyphen, not second hyphen

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (STRING VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @TABLE (STRING)
      SELECT 'E01234-1-1' 
UNION ALL SELECT 'E01234-1-200' 
UNION ALL SELECT 'E01234-1-3000' 
UNION ALL SELECT 'E01234-1-40000' 
UNION ALL SELECT 'E01234-1-500000' 
UNION ALL SELECT 'E01234-1-6000000' 
UNION ALL SELECT 'E01234-1-70000000' 
UNION ALL SELECT 'E01234444-1-800000000' 

SELECT LEFT(STRING, CHARINDEX('-',STRING)-1) STRIPPED_STRING from @TABLE
```

RETURNS 

`E01234
E01234
E01234
E01234
E01234
E01234
E01234
E01234444`

Comment: im using ms sql server 2012

Comment: Is the second `-` always the last one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL text before then Nth match?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163645/sql-text-before-then-nth-match)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need the second `-`:

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(STRING, CHARINDEX('-', @test, CHARINDEX('-', @test) + 1) -1) STRIPPED_STRING 
FROM @TABLE
```

Explanation: `CHARINDEX` will get you the index of the `-` - doing it twice (+ 1) specifies that the outter `CHARINDEX` should start at the spot after the first `-` in the string.

If you want to chop off everything after the last `-` instead (regardless of whether it's second or not):

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(STRING, LEN(STRING) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(STRING))) STRIPPED_STRING
FROM @table
```

This time, you get the `CHARINDEX` of the last (reverse the string) `-`, and subtract that from the length of the whole string.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @STR NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'E01234444-1-800000000';
SELECT LEFT(@STR, CHARINDEX('-', @STR, CHARINDEX('-', @STR)) - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL use something like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(fieldname, '-', 2) FROM tablename
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have `SUBSTRING_INDEX`

Comment: (In this poster's defense, the only tag on this post when this was posted was the `[sql]` tag. Maybe just mention that this would work for MySQL?)